# SQL AND operator logic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My logic is faulty.  Story of my life.  Anyway, I have the following query, which I believe is failing during the multiple string checks in one column.  I want to be able to check for multiple strings in one column with the `AND` operator.

Example, I want to suppress this email "dick1sucker@gmail.com" but I don't want to suppress "dickeynewman@gmail.com".  Using the `AND` operator below, it appears as if a record is suppressed if either one of the string checks occurs, even though I've surrounded the statement with parentheses.

```
/****** Script for CHECK DOMAIN SUFFIX AND VULGARITIES  ******/

SELECT EMAIL

INTO Matched_Table

FROM Matched_Table_TEMP

WHERE (RIGHT(RTRIM(EMAIL),4) IN ('.COM','.NET','.MIL','.GOV','.ORG','.BIZ') OR RIGHT(RTRIM(EMAIL),3) = '.US')

AND (CHARINDEX('DICK',EMAIL) = 0 and CHARINDEX('SUCKER',EMAIL) = 0)

AND (CHARINDEX('DICK',EMAIL) = 0 and CHARINDEX('HEAD',EMAIL) = 0)

AND (CHARINDEX('DICK',EMAIL) = 0 and CHARINDEX('CHOKE',EMAIL) = 0)

AND (CHARINDEX('DICK',EMAIL) = 0 and CHARINDEX('FACE',EMAIL) = 0)

AND (CHARINDEX('DICK',EMAIL) = 0 and CHARINDEX('NOSE',EMAIL) = 0)

AND (CHARINDEX('COCK',EMAIL) = 0 and CHARINDEX('SUCKER',EMAIL) = 0)
```

I will be adding plenty more vularities to the list, but obviously need the logic corrected first.

Another example, right now the above suppresses the following emails, but I don't want them suppressed.

METALHEAD038@HOTMAIL.COM

BAND2FACEDKITTY@AOL.COM

ANGELFACE30_98@YAHOO.COM

TERESADICKSON921@HOTMAIL.COM

ROARINGARTICHOKE@TOMGREEN.COM

CERNOSEK@YAHOO.COM

Comment: Are you using a case insensitive collation?

Comment: Duncan, sorry I should have noted that.  All data I'm comparing is upper case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all your internal `and`'s – the ones in lowercase – to `or`'s.

Your query is selecting the valid addresses, so a more natural way to write your exclusions is like this:

```
AND NOT (A != 0 and B != 0)
```

With boolean logic, to negate `p AND q` you need to negate both parts and change the `AND` to `OR`: `~p OR ~q`.

In your case:

```
AND (A = 0 or B = 0)
```

Comment: noa, your p's and q's boolean logic about to make my head explode!  This gave me the results I was looking for.  I'll have to test on more tables to make sure, but looks good so far.  Thanks, man.

Comment: Passed every test noa, thank you. Now that I look at it in this manner, it makes sense. For example, dickey@aol.com (CHARINDEX('DICK',EMAIL) = 0 OR CHARINDEX('SUCKER',EMAIL) = 0) The first part will = 1, while the second part will = 0.  The OR makes this work, the AND made it fail.

Comment: Glad it's making sense – Boolean logic almost always makes more sense with an example. When you get stuck, though, it often helps to write out your propositions in English and work through them formally. Please consider upvoting this and Aaron's answers if they were helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

These are all `AND` conditions. You don't have a clause that will currently allow an e-mail address that contains `dick` at all, regardless of what the rest of the e-mail is. If you want to allow `dick` but not `dick`...`head` you need to think about this a little differently. E.g.

```
DECLARE @Email VARCHAR(255) = 'dickeynewman@gmail.com';

SELECT @Email
WHERE 
(
  RIGHT(RTRIM(@Email),4) IN ('.COM','.NET','.MIL','.GOV','.ORG','.BIZ') 
  OR RIGHT(RTRIM(@Email),3) = '.US'
)
AND 
(
  (@Email NOT LIKE '%DICK%') 
  OR 
  (@Email LIKE '%DICK%' 
    AND @Email NOT LIKE '%SUCKER%'
    AND @Email NOT LIKE '%HEAD%'
    -- ...
  )
)
```

Comment: I'll take a look at this, too.  Thanks, Aaron.